# Upper bounding $\|\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac{(At)^k}{k!}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-exponential, matrix-norms

I'm trying to figure out the tightest upper bound for

$$\left \|\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac{(At)^k}{k!} \right\|,$$

where $A$ is a matrix and $\|A\|t > 1$. I know that $e^{\|A\|t}$ is a known upper bound, but I'm not sure if there's a tighter bound that depends on $N$.

I've tried the following:

$$ \left \|\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \frac{(At)^k}{k!} \right\| \leq \left \|(At)^N \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{1}{k!}  \right\| \leq e(\|A\|t)^N, $$

but I'm wondering if there's something better I'm missing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $(At)^k \leq (At)^N$? When is a matrix smaller than another one? Maybe you want to pull the norm inside the sum via the triangle inequality first.

Comment: Using the same notation for matrices and integers is confusing

Comment: The tightest upper bound is $\sum_{n=0}^N{\|A\|^nt^n\over n!}.$ For example it is attained for $A=I.$ Besides it can be estimated in terms of the greatest singular value.